# AWS KinesisEvents package not found when building Lambda function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I've been trying to build an AWS Lambda function for a .NET Core project (which is connected to a Kinesis stream) so that I can deploy the function to the cloud environment, but I keep getting the following error with my function: `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'KinesisEvents' does not exist in the namespace 'Amazon.Lambda' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`. I've made sure to install the latest version of [AWS SDK for .NET package AWSSDK.Kinesis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Kinesis/) as was advised [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.KinesisEvents) and I have
Amazon.Lambda.Templates version 3.8.1 installed. I also have the latest version of Amazon.Lambda.Tools installed (5.1.4) as well as .NET Core 2.1.9.

**What would be causing the `KinesisEvents` package name to not be recognized?**

Below is the code for the lambda:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.Kinesis;
using Amazon.Kinesis.Model;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.KinesisEvents;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace BookOnlineButton.PracticeBudgetAvailabilityLambda
{
    public class Function
    {

        /// <summary>
        ///
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FunctionHandler(KinesisEvent kinesisEvent, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Beginning to process {kinesisEvent.Records.Count} records...");

            foreach (var record in kinesisEvent.Records)
            {
                string recordData = GetRecordContents(record.Kinesis);
                context.Logger.LogLine($"Record Data:");
                context.Logger.LogLine(recordData);

            }

            context.Logger.LogLine("Stream processing complete.");
        }

        private string GetRecordContents(KinesisEvent.Record streamRecord)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(streamRecord.Data, Encoding.UTF8);
            try{
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally{
                reader?.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You try to delete Amazon.Lambda.Core from the reference, try importing.

Comment: can you share the .csproj file as well for better understanding of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Even though the KinesisEvents package is supposed to be a part of the `Amazon.Lamda` package, I ended up having to separately install the [Amazon.Lambda.KinesisEvents](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Lambda.KinesisEvents/) nuget package in order for the `KinesisEvents` type to be recognized.